# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-query'

Tags: reactjs, importerror, react-query

[I am refactoring a piece of code and it shows this type of error whenever I try to import "react-query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrwsm.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same thing and had to downgrade to version 3.

```
npm i react-query@3
```

Or for 4+

```
npm i @tanstack/react-query
```

Comment: Alright this actually solved my problem. I have to install a downgraded version of react-query

Answer (score 5):

It's because you are importing into a TypeScript file and it can't find the type declaration for the imported module. Normally all you need to do is to follow the given instructions and open a command prompt, go to the directory D:\overview and type:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/react-query
```

Comment: I tried this solution which you have suggested but it is not working

Comment: Because no such type dependency exists. This answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

react-query was renamed to `@tanstack/react-query` in v4. You need to rename all your imports from `react-query` to `@tanstack/react-query`.

You don't need to install @types/react-query. v4 is already written in typescript.