# React-query & typescript - Cannot find module '@tanstack/react-query' or its corresponding type declarations.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query, yarn-v2

I'm working on a react project with typescript (set up with `create-react-script`).
Following the [doc](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/installation)  I've installed react-query with

```
yarn add @tanstack/react-query
```

But I keep getting the typescript error: `Cannot find module '@tanstack/react-query' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Any idea of what I might be missing ?

While I could downgrade to react-query v3 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73213438/10613336), I'd rather have the v4 working.
Thanks for your help !

I tried

- removing and reinstalling react-query
- removing node_modules and re build my project

Comment: which version of tanstack/react-query is added?

Comment: From my package.json and yarn.lock it is version 4.20.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclusion to the story: I had **misconfigured my docker compose volume**. So, the package was installed in the container but not in local which explained the error in my IDE.

Sorry if I made someone lose his/her time and I hope it might still be of some use to others.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I spent more than an hour trying to fix it. Finally, It solved by restarting my IDE(VS code)- As simple as that. Give it a try, hope it will work for you too.